# SQL Server query for top rows to select with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to skip first 5 records and then select 10 records

I have a column `email` in table `user`. Here I am trying to select top 10 unique rows from table `user` using this query

```
select DISTINCT TOP 10 email from user
```

Now I am trying to select top 10 unique rows from table skipping the first 5 records

```
select DISTINCT SKIP 5 TOP 10 email from user
```

which is not done and return error.. can anyone help me

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 would have the new [`OFFSET` and `FETCH` keywords](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server-2012/sqlserver2012-offset-fetchnext-options-142174) to achieve exactly this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t2 as
(
select t1.*,
 row_number() over (order by id) rn 
from 
  (select email, max(id) as id from [user] group by email) as  t1
)

select * from t2 where rn between 5 and 10
```

Comment: thnks @valex for ans.. if i am having another field like id in the table which is unique.. can we use that for ordering and if yes... then how ? plz vote me up.. so that i can vote you up

Comment: Then use `GROUP BY` in the inner query and `OVER(ORDER BY ID)`. I've changed my answer using ID as a `order by` field.

Comment: yes.. this is working ... but what result i got is.. the rows which are repeating are not reflecting.. so duplicated rows are not selected.. at-least one row should be selected from the duplicate rows

Comment: plz @valex.. can u help me to solve this?? it would be great to learn from you... here duplicate rows are not selected.. i want to select one result.. as if there are 3 emails repeating then 1 result should be selected

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT A.NAME FROM
(SELECT distinct RANK() OVER(ORDER BY NAME) RNK,NAME FROM USERS) A
WHERE A.RNK>4 AND A.RNK<16
```

Using `LIMIT` will not guarantee you that you will get top rows with proper order.
If you use `ANALYTIC` functions, it will give you proper results.

[**SQL_LIVE_DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/598f5/2)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it. I like to use Common Table Expressions for some things like this because it makes the query easy to understand, although this isn't particularly complicated.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    Select Distinct Email From User
 )
 ,
 CTE1 AS
 (
    Select Email, ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY Email) AS RowNumber
    From CTE
 )

Select Top 10 * From CTE1 Where RowNumber > 5
```

Comment: thanks for replay..i tried this.. this is working properly.. but what if i don't want to order the data by email.. and if i just want to select the data in at sequence from the top of the database...

Comment: @merhardik: you're **not** ordering your data by `email` - that's **only** used to determine the sequential numbering. And in SQL Server, you **must** define some ordering - otherwise, there is no order (there's no *default* or *system* ordering)

Comment: okk.. if i am having another field like id in the table which is unique.. can we use that for ordering and if yes... then how ?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY email) AS row 
      FROM user ) a 
WHERE row > 5 and row <= 10
```

I think you are using SKIP incorrectly, it should be part of the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(10) Email FROM TableName WHERE Email not in (SELECT TOP(5) Email From TableName)
```

You can try this code, in this query fetch distinct 10 email ids skip 5 records as you say in this question.